# Is there any way to check is given link really exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

For example there are `lalalalaal.com` that do NOT exist. Is there any way using JavaScript (possibly with jQuery) to check is given link really exist?

Comment: "jQuery or JS" does not make sense. Perhaps you mean "JS, possibly using the jQuery library"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has to be a server involved because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) — but it doesn't necessarily follow that it has to be *your* server. :-)

You can use a third-party service such as Yahoo to do the proxying for you as discussed here: [*"Using YQL as a proxy for cross-domain Ajax"*](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax). That shows how to use jQuery to query YQL's JSON-P and JSON-P-X interfaces for another domain's content.

It's not complicated, from the article:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
          "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
          encodeURIComponent(url)+
          "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
  function(data){
    if(data.results[0]){
      container.html(data.results[0]);
    } else {
      var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
      container.html(errormsg);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, the response from another domain will always be null (the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies here).  You'd have to contact your own domain and have it check server-side if the site actually exists...but JavaScript alone can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

In order to find out if a URL exists, you have to make a request to it and see if you get a response. The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents JavaScript, running in a browser under normal security conditions, from reading responses from different hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, for security reasons (same domain policy).

Answer (score 0):

Use [AnyOrigin](http://anyorigin.com/) or the FOSS clone I made of it, [WhateverOrigin](http://whateverorigin.org/).